# Android RactiveNetwork crashing app when no strong network

Tags: java, android

I'm using the `'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:3.0.3'` from https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork

And here is my code

```
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
public void checkNetworkAvailable() {
    ReactiveNetwork
            .observeInternetConnectivity()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(isConnectedToInternet -> {
                changeOnlineStatus(isConnectedToInternet ? ConnectionQuality.EXCELLENT : ConnectionQuality.POOR);

            });
}

private void changeOnlineStatus(ConnectionQuality connectionQuality) {
    if (connectionQuality == ConnectionQuality.EXCELLENT) {
        // do something
        if (isTrue) {
            Snackbar.make(getView(), "Internet Connected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (connectionQuality == ConnectionQuality.POOR) {
        // do something
        isTrue = true;
        final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "No Internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackBar.setAction("DISMISS", v -> {
            // Call your action method here
            snackBar.dismiss();
        });
        snackBar.show();
    } else if (connectionQuality == ConnectionQuality.UNKNOWN) {

        isTrue = true;
        final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Unknown network", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackBar.setAction("DISMISS", v -> {
            // Call your action method here
            snackBar.dismiss();
        });
        snackBar.show();
        // do something
    }
}
```

I have added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` into application manifest.

Still app keeps crashing. Is there anyone using the library and facing same network?

I chose the library because it test if phone actually have access to internet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the error

```
E: Could not establish connection with WalledGardenStrategy
                      java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
                          at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:212)
                          at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
                          at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
                          at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
                          at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
                          at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:609)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
```

Even if connection timeout, is there anyway to handle this?
I also noticed is only when i'm having unstable network that the code crash the app, which caused the timeout.

Comment: Check this :https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork/issues/228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to pwittchen, the owner of ReactiveNetwork library for his quick reposne. I resolve the problem using onError method in `rxjava`

```
    public void checkNetworkAvailable() {

    ReactiveNetwork
            .observeInternetConnectivity()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d) {
                    // this will be invoked before operation is started
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(final Boolean isConnectedToInternet) {
                    // do your action, when you're connected to the internet
                    changeOnlineStatus(isConnectedToInternet ? ConnectionQuality.EXCELLENT : ConnectionQuality.POOR);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(final Throwable e) {
                    // handle an error here <-----------------
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Network timeout!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // this will be invoked when operation is completed
                }

            });
}
```